# Why aren't my flexbox items wrapping next to each other?

Tags: javascript, flexbox

I have a Flexbox container with the following SCSS:

```
.picker {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

My flex items have the following SCSS:

```
.pickeritem {
  height: 25px;
  width: 130px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the container is wrapping the items to the center of the div rather than next to the other items like so:

[image]

How do I make items 3 to 8 wrap next to each other leaving all of the white space to the right of the div?

Can this be achieved without using any sort of row and column methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the align-content property. I also made some other minor changes and added color and border for better visualization.

```css
.picker {
  height: 75px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
}



.pickeritem {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fbbdbd;
}
```

```html
<div class='picker'>
  <div class='pickeritem'>1</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>2</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>3</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>4</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>5</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>6</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>7</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>8</div>
  <div class='pickeritem'>9</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```css
.picker {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

```css
.pickeritem {
  height: 25px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: `justify-content:flex-start` is the default I believe. I put it in anyway but as I expected this didn't do anything.

Comment: I think this is because you have fixed the width of flex-item = 130px, remove that width property from flex-item